# sql server - database with stored procedures using all of memory on server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database with two tables that are filled with data from parallel processes running inserting data using stored procedures. The sql server is practically using all of the physical memory and I noticed that some tables were missing data and when I dbugged, I found that due to timeout errors data was not being inserted since I did not account for this. Someone told me to run exec who2 and looking at all the transactions associated with this application it looks as follows

```
spid   status   login    hostname    blkby  dbname   command ......

738    sleeping  sa      R120         .     FeedsRS   AWAITING COMMAND
739    sleeping  sa      R120         .     FeedsRS   AWAITING COMMAND
740    sleeping  sa      R120         .     FeedsRS   AWAITING COMMAND
```

Now there are about 800 of these and I am not sure what it means. If the transactions are locked, is there a way to end them without data problems, while I add code to handle the timeout errors. I am not even certain if this is the problem but should I also set the lock timeout to a reasonable value instead of the 0 default.
Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably one of:

- You aren't closing connections
- You have poor transaction handling

And SQL Server will use most memory by default: it's isn't a leak or a bug.

To check for open transactions

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran > 0
```

Comment: it shows no  open transactions..what does this mean, appreciate your response

Comment: is it worth opening and closing the connection for each transaction of which there are 100s of thousands and processing between the next transaction takes 3 seconds to complete...and the whole process runs all the time

Comment: See [Connection pooling](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Connection+pooling).. they aren't *really* closed...